# Add custom view to NavigationBar using MasterDetailPage on Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigationbar, master-detail, custom-view

I work on a xamarin project. And I would like to add a custom view as MyPersonalizedView which is in PCL project (Not a ToolBarItem !) to my NavigationBar. I use a MasterDetailPage.

By using renderer, I managed to make what I wanted only on Android but not on iOS...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: If you can access the `UINavigationBar` there is a `TitleView` property that let's you set any `UIView` to be added to the center of the NavigationBar. Could that work?

Comment: Thanks for your help !
But I managed to change color from UINavigationBar with "UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Purple;", but there is not a TitleView ....

Comment: I apologize - it's in the `UINavigationItem` and not directly in the bar. You have to access `yourNavigationBar.TopItem.TitleView` to set that view. You need an instance of the navigation bar. It can't be set just from the class.

Comment: Thanks ! It's work fine.
Finally, in my NavigationRenderer, in ViewDidLoad(), I use this code :
"           var coverView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 20, 64));
            coverView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;          
            NavigationBar.TopItem.TitleView = coverView;"